# CMD delete files with wildcard in subdirectory

Tags: cmd, wildcard, del

If I want to do this in CMD

```
rm D:/archive/*/*2017*
```

what command I have to use?

I try this and it does not work.

```
del D:/archive/*/*2017*
```

The solution I come up with is, and it works.

```
cd "D:/archive"
for /F %i in ('dir /AD /B') do del %i\*2017*
```

If anyone has an easier solution please suggest me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards (`*`, `?`) are only resolved when they appear in the *last* element of a path, so there is not an easier solution for this.

Your `for /F` loop approach is even not comprehensive enough, because it is not safe:

- the `cd` command would not change to the expected directory when the current working directory is on another drive but `D:`, so the `/D` switch is missing;
- special characters (like `&`, `^`, `(`, `)`, for instance) might lead to unexpected behaviour, since you did not put quotation marks around all the paths;
- there is no option string provided for `for /F`, so it would split directory names at the first white-space character due to the `delims` option defaulting to <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and it would ignore directories whose names begin with `;` due to the default `eol` option;
- the path separator in Windows is the backslash `\`, the forward slash `/` might lead to errors;

Here is the fixed code:

```cmd
cd /D "D:\archive" & for /F "delims= eol=|" %I in ('dir /B /A:D') do @del "%I\*2017*"
```

To make it simpler, you could also use a `for /D` loop instead of `for /F`, like this, so there is no more `cd` command required:

```cmd
for /D %I in ("D:\archive\*") do @del "%~I\*2017*"
```